# How to stop SQL Server CE 3.5 change tracking table from growing infinitely?

Tags: sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

We are using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 to sync between a SQL Server database and a SQL Server CE 3.5 database. What appears to be happening is a change tracking private table is filling up in the SQL Server CE database until the file reaches its maximum size then fails.

The table is `__sysOCSDeletedRows`. Change tracking is enabled on the server. Does anyone know if we can turn off change tracking on the CE database or if there's some Sync options to prevent this table from growing?

We are only syncing in one direction and never writing to the CE database other than via Sync.

EDIT: I got the offending table wrong in original post.

Answer (score 1):

which sync provider are you using?

if you're using the SqlCeSyncProvider, you can use the [SqlCeSyncStoreMetadataCleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.sqlserverce.sqlcesyncstoremetadatacleanup.aspx)  API

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not using that provider. We are using SqlCeClientSyncProvider. I did notice that the provider has a RetentionInDays property but it doesn't seem to affect the table in question.

Comment: what's the value you set for the RetentionInDays? if the value is greater than zero, sync fx will delete metadata older than the retention days everytime you sync.

Comment: I used a non-zero value. I can't seem to make it have any effect. I set the retention right after creating the object.

Comment: What do you mean you set it after you create the object?

Comment: Sorry, I mean after the SqlCeClientSyncProvider is instantiated, I set the retention to, say, 1 day. Nothing gets trimmed from the deleted objects table.

Answer (score 0):

Allow the database to be larger than the default by using the "Max Database Size=4091" connection string option

Comment: All that does is delay the inevitable!